# how to use matlab to calculate double integration?

Tags: integration, matlab

I want to use Matlab to verify the result of double integration.

$$\int_{-w}^{w}\int_{l}^{x}e^{ay}\space dydx$$

I tried this one

> ```
> func = @(x,y) (exp(a.*y));
> result = integral2(func,l,x,-w,w);
> ```

But it didn`t work, how to deal with it?

Comment: $$\begin{array}{l} \text{syms a x y w l} \\
\text{int(int(exp(a*y), y, l,x),x,-w,w)} \\ \\ \text{ >> (2*(sinh(a*w) - a*w*exp(a*l)))/a^2}\end{array}$$